# Path in Header LIne, Truncated

Tags: header-line

I have the path displayed in the [Header Line](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HeaderLine), but it is truncated when the path is too long. Is there any way to wrap it to go on the next line?

Answer (score 0):

No, the header line is only ever one line.

Comment: Any other way I can view the actual filename, cause when I have split screen on a tiny monitor, I can't see what the actual filename is.

Comment: You could scroll horizontally, or you could use `C-x C-b`.